# Alert button's inner content after clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, alert, innerhtml

Please, help fix bug: the code currently alerts undefined instead of button's inner contents

```
 function registerClickHandler() {
   $('#clickme').click(function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
       alert(this.innerHTML);
     }, 200);
   });
 }
```

Comment: This is because setTimeout function has now lost the scope for 'this', try passing what it is you're trying to refer into the setTimeout function in the function() parameters.

Comment: It's a question from a recruitment test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside the timeout handler is not the button

```
function registerClickHandler() {
    $('#clickme').click(function (e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert(e.currentTarget.innerHTML);
        }, 200);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the value before setTimeout

```
  function registerClickHandler() {
        $('#clickme').click(function () {
            var value=this.innerHTML;
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert(value);
            }, 200);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In java script `this` points to the last function and inside the timeout handler is not the button, thats why you are getting the error.

Also it's a good practice implement this kind of functions or onclicks using `on.('click', function(){...})`

below you can see my example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clickme').on('click', function (e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert(e.currentTarget.innerHTML);
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

You can take a look and run it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/6qwk0g1t/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the click eventhandler outside the function. Also pass the value of 'this' to a variable before calling setTimout. Later use this variable inside setTimout. Read more about Javascrpt prototypes [here](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#clickme').click(function() {
    var me = this;
         setTimeout(function() {
           alert(me.innerHTML);
         }, 200);
       });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickme">click me</div>
```